# Not able to display images in Recyclerview using Picasso

Tags: java, android

I had my array of names and images here added to ArrayList

```
   private ArrayList prepareData()
{
    ArrayList android_version = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<android_version_names.length; i++)
    {
        MovieNew movieNew = new MovieNew();
        movieNew.setPicName(android_version_names[i]);
        movieNew.setProfile_pic(android_image_urls[i]);
        android_version.add(movieNew);
    }
    return android_version;
}
```

Adapter.class

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
    MovieNew movieList = movie.get(position);
    holder.tv_android.setText(movieList.getPicName());
   Picasso.with(context).load(movieList.getProfile_pic()).into(holder.img_android);
}
```

i can see the URL in load() while debugging  but it is not getting loaded into the Imageview. url=null if i see Evaluate Expression

Can someone help me how to figure out this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the size of your ImageView.  Maybe the image is being loaded, but with a size of 0. Also try to copy the and paste the url on your browser to check if the url is well formed.

Comment: i tried using Picasso.with(context).load(movieList.getProfile_pic()).resize(60, 20).into(holder.img_android);            but still i don't change the image displaying?url is also displaying image.

Comment: holder.img_android, please check if this variable is initialized with the correct view. can you show me your layout?

Comment: <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_android"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"  />

Comment: img_android = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_android);

Comment: Substitute movieList.getProfile_pic() with this url http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/cute-dog-shiba-inu-ryuji-japan-57.jpg and let me know what happens

Comment: Also try to use itemView.getContext() as context.

Comment: i followed this tutorial https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/image-loading-recyclerview-picasso.html